# Ruby LoadError on OEL

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I’ve just installed ruby on an OEL 5.8 server and am seeing some strange behaviour

Server details

```
 Linux myhost 2.6.18-238.el5 #1 SMP Tue Jan 4 15:41:11 EST 2011 x86_64 x86
```

Ruby version

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

when I try and run a ruby program I get an odd error

```
 -sh-3.2$ ruby testing.rb
 ruby: No such file or directory -- ('» (LoadError)
```

similarly calling gem returns a similar error

```
-sh-3.2$ gem -v
/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- (W
(LoadError)
```

Running a strace on ruby shows this error before it dies

```
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb",  {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1871, ...}) = 0
open("(\227I\6", O_RDONLY)              = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(2, "ruby", 4ruby)                     = 4
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "No such file or directory -- (\227I"..., 33No such file or directory -- (I) = 33
write(2, " (", 2 ()                       = 2
write(2, "LoadError", 9LoadError)                = 9
write(2, ")\n", 2)
)                      = 2
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x1, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x319d00eb10}, {0x4b1eb0, [],   SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x319d00eb10}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x319d00eb10}, {0x1, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x319d00eb10}, 8) = 0
write(4, "!", 1)                        = 1
munmap(0x2ac6c5784000, 1052672)         = 0
exit_group(1)
```

I have the full output if anyone wants to see it

strangly each time I call ruby I get a slightly different error message (e.g)

```
-sh-3.2$ ruby testing.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- (Ç/ (LoadError)
-sh-3.2$ ruby testing.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- Ç (LoadError)
-sh-3.2$ ruby testing.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- 0w;   (LoadError)
-sh-3.2$ ruby testing.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- NULLCMD (LoadError)
-sh-3.2$ ruby testing.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- 07î (LoadError)
```

and in each case my strace shows errors like this before it dies

```
lstat("/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1871, ...}) = 0
open("\20\7\3\30", O_RDONLY)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I noticed this happening  weeks ago and did a reinstall of ruby which fixed it, but at 4am yesterday the problem happened again which is very strange as the box was no being used during that period

I have done the usual stuff like checking for other versions of Ruby and all looks fine so I'm a bit stuck on this one

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing it? And more importantly how to fix it

Cheers

Mike

Comment: Is everything else working normally on that box? Almost seems like memory or disk corruption happening since the error is different each time. However since the error seems to be coming from rubygems you could try running without it and see what happens: `ruby --disable-gems testing.rb`.

Comment: everything else is fine on that box, the problem isn't just linked to rubygems thats just an example of something else that affected
my test script that I'm calling above just echoes out a line of text so it doesn't use any gems
it's really strange

Comment: Just for testing, maybe try and compile and install ruby 1.8 on it and see what happens? Also there is a newer version of 1.9 available (p374). Did you compile it yourself from scratch?

Comment: hi Casper
yep I compiled ruby myself, I did originally have an earlier version of ruby on that box (1.9.2) but moved to 1.9.3 a while ago, I have been using it on another test server for a few months with no problems so am unsure what the issue is with this one
I'll do some testing with a newer version and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into this problem on a system running RHEL 6.3. The prelink package runs once a day and corrupts the ruby binary. I uninstalled prelink and replaced the ruby binary.

Comment: ah I was looking at prelink as it seemed to happen now and again when that ran, thanks for that I'll get rid of that cronjob now